# Why does the CQS principle require a Command not to return any value?

Tags: command-query-separation

The CQS principle says every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.
It makes sense for a Query not to do anything else, because you don't expect a query to change the state. 
But it looks harmless if a Command returns some extra piece of information. You can either use the returned value or ignore it. Why does the CQS principle require a Command not to return any values?

Answer (score 2):

> But it looks harmless if a Command returns some extra piece of information?

It often is. It sometimes isn't.

People can start confusing queries for commands, or calling commands more for the information it returns than for its effect (along with "clever" ways of preventing that effect from being a real effect, that can be brittle).

It can lead to gaps in an interface. If the only use-case people can envision for a particular query is hand-in-hand with a particular command, it may seem pointless to add the pure form of the query (e.g. writing a stack with a `Pop()` but no `Peek()`) which can restrict the flexibility of the component in the face of future changes.

In a way, "looks harmless" is exactly what CQS is warning you about, in banning such constructs.

Now, that isn't to say that you might not still decide that a particular command-query combination isn't so useful to be worth it, but in weighing up the pros and cons of such a decision, CQS is always a voice arguing against it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, one of the benefits of CQS is how well it works in distributed environments. Commands become their own isolated unit that could be immediately executed, placed in a queue to be executed at a later date, executed by a remote event handler etc.

If the commander interface were to specify a return type then you greatly affect the strength of the CQS pattern in its ability to fit well within a distributed model.

The common approach to solving this problem ([see this article for instance by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids/)) is to generate a unique ID such as a guid which is unique to the event executed by the command handler. This is then persisted to allow the data to be identified at a later date.